# paginate results in ElasticSearch like sphinx

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, pagination, fetch, sphinx

We are using ElasticSearch for our search engine. When we fetch many results like 50k for some keywords, then the search took 1s at all. But when we fetch for example 10k results it took 100ms .

In sphinx, there is a setting, where it is possible to limit the fetched documents to 1000 for example. Is there some option in elasticsearch as well? We don't need all 50k results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is from/size option for elasticsearch for example first 10 docs

```
{
    "from" : 0, "size" : 10,
    "query" : {
        ....
    }
}
```

here is the [api doc](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html)

Comment: Not really, this is the limit of results, which should be returned from ES. There is difference between the fetched and returned results.